# Удаление картинки в модальном окне используя ajax и php

Tags: php, ajax, post

Подскажите как сделать удаление картинки в модальном окне. Удалить нужно из базы(путь картинки).

Есть таблица **images** (содержит картинки товаров) и таблица имеет **3 поля**:

1. **id** - A_U поле
2. **name** - (varchar 255) содержит путь картинки "/i/20160418.jpg"
3. **tovars_id** - связывает картинку с товаром. (1 товар у меня может иметь несколько картинок)

В общем у меня проблема с удалением. Код написан. Проблема такая при нажатии на картинку снизу (красным квадратом обвел на скриншоте) у меня виснет весь сайт и ни чего нельзя сделать, даже не могу посмотреть во вкладке Network что туда приходит (браузер Google Chrome).

Картинки в модальном окне выводятся циклом foreach через  php.

[image]

```
$_POST[upload]- это кнопка Загрузить
if($_POST[upload])
{   

    $id=$_POST[id];
    $uploaddir = '/i/';
    foreach ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $m=>$w){ 

    if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$m] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$m]<=1024000))
    {
        $ex = explode('.',$w);
        $ex= end($ex);
        $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.'.$ex;
        $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$m], $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].$uploadfile))
       {
        $c="INSERT INTO images (name, tovars_id) VALUES('$uploadfile', '$id')"; 

        $query=$dbh->prepare($c);

        $query->execute();

        }       
    } 
}       
   header("Location: /pr1.php");
    exit;
  /*Код ниже отвечает за удаление картинки*/ 
} elseif($_POST[image_delete]){
        $id=$_POST[image_id]; 
        $src=$_POST[src];
        $c="DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id=$id";
        $query1=$dbh->prepare($c);
        $query1->execute();
}
else{
    echo"Error2";
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$(".modal_images").click(function(){
    id=this.dataset.id; //получаю id картинки
    src=this.attributes.src;// получаю путь картинки
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "exit.php",
  data: {image_id:id, src: src, image_delete: 'true'} ,
  success: function(msg){
    alert( "Прибыли данные: " + msg );
  }
});
});
```

**HTML & PHP**

Тут выводятся картинки из базы.

```
<? foreach($rows as $k=>$img){ ?>
<img id="output_<?=$k?>" data-id="<?=$img[id]?>" class="modal_images" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="<?= $img['name'] ?>">
<?}?>
```

Люди помогите разобраться почему страница виснет и не срабатывает клик по картинке. Я уже не знаю как решить свою проблему. Может модальное окно не подходит для решения такой задачи или есть другая теория.

Answer (score 1):

Если зависает вся страница вместе с консолью, значит происходит зависание интерфейса, вызванное JavaScript кодом. Например, цикл while, в котором условие всегда срабатывает. На данном куске кода никаких подобных циклов нет, значит, возможно, кто-то еще слушает клик по картинке. Возможно, плагин, реализующий модальное окно, слушает клик по самому себе и как-то неправильно себя ведет. Особенно актуально если плагин самописный. Из данного кода зависание интерфейса может создавать (и создает) только alert, но вы должны бы были увидеть окошко хрома при этом. Маловероятная ситуация, но у меня например убунта любит делать присобаченный к ноуту монитор главным в связке и все алярмы отправляет на него, правда, к алертам хрома это не относится. Я бы на всякий случай заменил alert() на console.log() и в будущем всю отладку делал через консоль. Чтобы что-то узнать дальше нужно больше данных.

Comment: а можете предложить альтернативный вариант удаления картинки ?